# How to format numeric cells with the thousands separator (e.g. 412,335 not 412335) in a React material-table

Tags: material-table

On a [Material-Table](https://material-table.com), the `columns` have a property [`type`](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-prop) which can be

> Data type: 'boolean', 'numeric', 'date', 'datetime', 'time', 'currency'

I tried `numeric` but it didn't format large numbers with commas.  For example, instead of "412335" I need to format it as "412,335".  The `currency` type does add commas.

I know I can define a custom cell, but I'd like to avoid customizations because they're a maintenance problem.

I've also seen [Custom Column Rendering](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering) as a possible solution, but my cells are supposed to be editable so when the user edits the cell, I'd prefer the commas to go away.  I'm looking for a solution that operates at the display level.  I mean, when it displays the value "412335" it should display it with commas as "412,335" but it should not affect the underlying value.

Lastly, I'd like a solution which takes localization into account because some of our users might be in countries that don't use commas as a thousands separator.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to define a custom cell then you're going to have to change the value before passing it into the data table. Whether you use a custom cell or not, you can use [toLocaleString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) `number.toLocaleString([locale [, options ]])` to convert your number to a localized string.

If you want to turn that back into a number without commas or other separators for sorting or editing, you can use `parseFloat(number)`

Answer (score 1):

Answering in case someone else faces the same problem.
Custom Column Rendering would be the way to solve that.

When editing values, Material Table uses the `field` value of the column when editing, not the `render` output.

```js
let columns = [
  {
    title: "amount",
    field: "amount",
    render: (expense) => expense.amount.toLocaleString(),
  },
];

<MaterialTable title="Expenses" columns={columns} />;
```